# Moodle: Clean up database

Tags: moodle

I have a LMS site developed in Moodle. It has a lot of data which has been added by my QA team. This data includes users, forums, posts etc.

Moodle has some weird behaviour in terms of cleaning up site. e.g. If we are deleting users from admin account, the entry still remains in database table {user}. Most probably it is because that deleted user may have other historical posts. But there is no way to clean up deleted user from database. My client wants a clean copy of application on production.

Could someone help with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used following:

1. Logged in with SSH
2. Executed following command from putty: `php /path/to/moodle/admin/cli/fix_deleted_users.php`
3. Then went in Database and put following query: `DELETE FROM mdl_user WHERE deleted = 1`

Everything was working properly. Basically, `fix_deleted_users.php` removes all references of deleted user and then leaves those empty deleted users in `mdl_user` table which can be further deleted. We only need to take care of third party plugins that may use deleted user's ID but in my case, I did not installed any plugin so it went successful.

Surprisingly, I did not find any documentation on this file on internet. Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

You are right that users are not deleted from the database (and for exactly the reason you guessed - there are still records on the system referencing that userid, so the record needs to keep existing; also it is possible to restore users in some circumstances, so they need to be retained for that).

If you want a clean copy of Moodle on the production site, then just start with a clean install.

If that is not really what you want, but instead want some of the configuration settings and some (all?) of the courses, then it is no longer a 'clean' copy, but you could try the following:

- Use the Moodle flavours plugin to copy the system settings - https://moodle.org/plugins/view/local_flavours
- Use backup & restore to copy any courses you want to transfer (with or without user data, at your choice).
- You might be able to use the [Moosh](http://moosh-online.com/) commands 'course-backup' and 'course-restore' (alongside 'category-export' and 'category-import') to simplify some of the backup & restore process.

Comment: I'm going to try flavours plugin. But they should have given simplified method to deploy application.

Comment: Who should have given this? I'm not quite sure what you are wanting - deploying a Moodle site is very simple, set config.php, run install. If you are wanting to transfer a set of config from one site to another, then the flavours plugin does that. If you want to transfer all the data, then just export the database and import it.

Comment: Yes but there are lot of data which we do not expect to transfer along with production development. Exporting QA application will also have unnecessary data (e.g. in users table with their testing posts)